# высчитать математическое выражение со скобками из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

есть код:

```
str = "(100+100)/100"
print(int(str))
```

задача кода: высчитать математическое выражение со скобками из строки

у меня сделать не получается, т.к. недостаточно опыта.
помогите пожалуйста

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Желательно переименовать переменную, т.к. `str` Это тип данных в python.

```
s = "(100+100)/100"
print(eval(s))
```